# How to apply multiple events to the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, function

I'm not the best at this jquery stuff. But I'm trying to seperate the action from the function so I can apply multiple events that cause the same function. Unfortunately this isn't working. Anyone know why?

**Updated Function, but still errors**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $info_items = jQuery('.checkbox.has_info, .has_info');

$info_items.click(function(event) {
$(this).show_text(event);
});


// I suspect it has something to do with this initalizer of the function here 

jQuery.fn.show_text = function(event){
  var $info_item = jQuery(this);
  $info_items.filter(function(index){
    return $(".hidden_text").css("display","block");
    }).not($info_item).parent().next().next().hide("slow");
  $info_item.parent().next().next().show("fast");
});

});
```

Comment: Please use a better subject line next time. Perhaps something like "How to apply multiple events to the same function".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is `e`, the event?  You need to name the event argument to the `click()` function to use it.  Also, to invoke `show_text` such that it has a `this`, you need to invoke it on an element:

```
$info_items.click(function (event) {
  // 'this' is the element in $info_items which was clicked

  // invoke show_text on the element in question
  $(this).show_text(event);
});
```

You also have an extra `)` on your final `});` line.

Comment: I thought maybe I had to pass an event to it for the 'this' to work. But I've taken it out, and it still errors out. I understand your example, but I'm trying not to do that so that I can have multiple events fire the same function.

Comment: Thanks for updating. I tried this, and it still bombs. If I comment out the entire function, it's good. ;)  . So maybe that initializing syntax is wrong on my end?

Comment: Are you executing this inside a `$(function() { })`? What is `$info_items`? Without more info, we cannot help.

Comment: added $info_items above ;) this is also inside a $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Also, is your browser giving you an error message? If not, run your code through Firefox and install Firebug.

Comment: Running firebug. But it's given me some other random error, and it errors out my entire javascript library instead of telling me where its breaking. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery `bind` to attach several events to a single function.

```
$('#whatever').bind('mouseover focus click', function() {
   your_custom_function();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var handle = function(event) {
  $(event.currentTarget).show_text(event);
};
$info_items.bind('click blur', handle);
```

Comment: Does the listener have to explicitly come after the function?

Comment: if you define your handler function as a local variable, yes. If you define it as a named function (even if its a local named function), the listener can come first.